# What is an adjective for an action that was performed well under pressure?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard the word "clutch" used with this meaning (eg: "That was clutch!"), but is there a more sophisticated or well-codified word for such?

Example: "That was [adjective] when you answered the question correctly after the teacher so rudely shook you awake."

Comment: Well, Hemingway once described courage as "grace under pressure." Perhaps "courageous" would work in your context.

Comment: Perhaps a synonym of *impressive* or *clever*.

Comment: @user888379 Actually Hemingway never attached the word courage or guts to that phrase. It was used as a standalone. See https://muse.jhu.edu/article/440083/pdf — which notes this misconception and quotes Hemingway saying, in a letter to Fitzgerald, "Was not referring to guts but something else. Grace under pressure. Guts never made any money for anybody except violin string manufacturers."

Comment: @LyovinK Thanks for the info! Next time I'll attribute it to Abraham Lincoln, in accordance with the immemorial traditions of the Internet.

Comment: *Clutch* is the most appropriate word; no other word expresses what it does as well.

Answer (score 1):

Clutch, is a term popularized by gaming. In a match with other players, if you were the last player standing against a team of 4, and you managed against all odds to win the game, you would consider that a "clutch". Various uses of this word like, "That was clutch" are kind of incorrect because you would be more accurate to say that "it was a clutch".

However with slang like this there are no real rules. As for a sophisticated version of.

Meaning: Winning under pressure against overwhelming odds.

Where the opposite would be to "Choke".

I cannot find any word that is a more sophisticated way to refer to this extremely specific instance. I suspect that is why the word now exists in this context.

Supervene might be the closest word i could come up with but it doesn't quite describe the same scenario.